# Problem in creating User in SqlServer using smo

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

1) If there is already a login 'user1' then I create a user 'user1' for database 'db1' by calling  `CreateDatabaseUser`  function

2) Else, I create a login 'user1' with password 'password1' with default database as 'db1' (only after creating db1) using  `CreateServerLogin`  and then I create user 'user1' for 'db1' using  `CreateDatabaseUser`

Method (2) throws an exception at 
 `newUser.Create();`  in  `CreateDatabaseUser`

saying,  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Create failed for User 'user1'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. --- > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: '[user1]' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.`

What could be the problem?

```
private static Login CreateServerLogin(Server server, string database, string login, string password)
{
    var newLogin = new Login(server, login)
                       {
                           LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin,
                           DefaultDatabase = database,
                           PasswordPolicyEnforced = false
                       };

    newLogin.Create(password);

    return newLogin;
}

private static User CreateDatabaseUser(Database database, string user, string login)
{            
    var newUser = new User(database, user) { UserType = UserType.SqlLogin, Login = login };

    newUser.Create();
    newUser.AddToRole("db_owner");
    return newUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check up transactions and batches.

DDL statements also support transactions, so when you create new user and pass server login, there might not be such login on the server because previous statement being not committed.

Also batch close statement "GO" would help

---

Try first:

- CreateServerLogin
- issue GO
- CreateDBLogin
- issue COMMIT

---

if failed try this logic:

- CreateServerLogin
- issue COMMIT
- CreateDBLogin