# What is the equivalent of the 'GO' statement when using SMO with Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

This is a snippet from my powershell module which creates a login and user in a database:

```
# code omitted which sets default db, language, etc.
$login.Create()

$user = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User") $db, $username
$user.Login = $login.Name
$user.Create()
```

An exception is being thrown on the call to `$user.Create()` with the following message:

**Windows NT user or group '[domain\user]' not found. Check the name again.**

However `$login.Create()` executes without a problem and I can see in SSMS that the login exists.

The only thing that comes to mind why this error is being thrown is if I was doing this through T-SQL I'd write the following:

```
CREATE USER [domain\user] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
CREATE USER [user] FOR [domain\user];
GO
```

[Question regarding issuing a GO statement after CREATE LOGIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520589/problem-in-creating-user-in-sqlserver-using-smo)

How is this achieved in PowerShell? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Curious, should it be `$user.Login = $login` ?

Comment: No, according to MSDN it asks for a `String` rather than a `Login` object. Trying it with a `Login` object throws an exception along the lines of 'no overload found.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I changed, but the script seems to be working now. I'll post the full script anyway, and maybe someone can tell me. -shrug-

```
Function Add-DatabaseUser
{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="The domain account to create the account for.", Position = 0)]
    [string] $loginname
   ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="The user name for the new account.", Position = 1)]
    [string] $username
   ,[Parameter(HelpMessage="Make this user an database administrator?")]
    [switch] $dbadmin
)

$srv = Get-Server
$db = Get-Database

$login = $null;
$user = $null;

Try
{
    $login = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login") $srv, $loginname
    $login.DefaultDatabase = "MyDatabase"
    $login.Language = "British English"
    $login.LoginType = "WindowsUser"
    $login.Create()
}
Catch
{
    $exception = $_.Exception
    while($exception.InnerException -ne $null)
    {
        $exception = $exception.InnerException
    }

    Write-Error $exception.Message

    return
}

Try
{
    $user = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User") $db, $username
    $user.Login = $login.Name
    $user.Create()

    if ($administrator)
    {
        $user.AddToRole("db_datareader")
        $user.AddToRole("db_datawriter")
        $user.Alter()
    }
}
Catch
{
    $exception = $_.Exception
    while($exception.InnerException -ne $null)
    {
        $exception = $exception.InnerException
    }

    Write-Error $exception.Message

    return
}

Write-Host "User was successfully created."
return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If $DB is just a string holding a database name change that to be

```
$db = $server.Databases['YourDatabaseNameHere']
```

You might also try changing the $user creation line to

```
$user = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User") $db, $login.Name
$user.Create()
```

That last shouldn't be necessary but it's what I use that works.  If that still doesn't work you might want to post more of your code.

Comment: $db is a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database` object, but that part seems to work OK. I'll try the second snippet and get back to you.

Comment: If you can try to stop after the $login.Create() command and use SSMS or the like to make sure the login was really created.

Comment: The login is created, as soon as that line is executed, I can see the login under the Logins folder in SSMS. The problem seems to be fixed now, but it's a shame I don't know how. =/